# If I am downloading an S3 object from an EC2 instance, does this request leave the Amazon network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I am downloading an S3 object from an EC2 instance, does this request leave the Amazon network, or is the request made via Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the EC2 instance and S3 bucket are in the same region or not.

> All communication between regions is across the public Internet.

You can read more about AWS regions and availability zones [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-regions-availability-zones). Communication within the same region happens over low-latency private links:

> Availability Zones are connected to each other with fast, private
>   fiber-optic networking.

See [AWS Global Infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/).

**EDIT**

Although data transfer happens over private links within the same region, accessing the API endpoints using the SDK or CLI still requires Internet access. See [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).

If you're concerned about security in Java SDK, [the default client configuration is to use HTTPS for all requests for increased security](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html). (Although individual clients can also override this setting by explicitly including the protocol as part of the endpoint URL when calling `AmazonWebServiceClient.setEndpoint(String)`)

If you're concerned about data transfer cost, all inbound traffic from S3 to EC2 is [free of charge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).

Comment: Thank you very much. If the EC2 and S3 are in the same region, does communication happen within the Amazon network? Also I'm using the Java SDK for AWS to get an object from S3. In this case an HTTP connection is established. Is  this connection over the public internet?

Comment: Within the same region, communication happens across low-latency private links. However, SDK requests to service endpoints require Internet access. See my update answer.